# How can I change the permissions of a folder from create or delete to list files only on a NTFS partition?

Tags: permissions

I have many NTFS partitions on my PC.

If I change the permissions of a folder on a NTFS partition from "create and delete files" to "list files only", its permissions will return to "create and delete files" permissions.

But, if I copy that folder and paste it onto the desktop, a Linux partition, the feature works. That is, it will change from "create and delete files" to "list files only".

How can I make the permission changes stay without copying the folder to my desktop?

Comment: Can you please list the specific commands that you used as well the ls -l output results?

Comment: sorry i am a new user for ubuntu i didn't understand your question maggotbrain,commands used means terminal commands?or any other

Answer (score 1):

## On Linux partitions, in Linux (example: ext4, reiserFS)

In Linux, if you don't have the ownership of a file, you wont be able to change the permissions. You can use sudo to change the permissions for a file you don't own.

It is possible to launch Nautilus as root by doing alt+F2, then: `gksudo nautilus`

The system will ask for your password. This way, you can change any permission on any file. Take care, it is possible to change permissions or delete system files too!

## On Windows partitions, in Linux

On partitions like NTFS and Fat, there are not so many rights like in Linux/Unix filesystems:

1. On Fat partition, there are no right management;
2. On NTFS partition, ownership can be managed.

## Your case

Once a file from a NTFS partition is copied on your desktop, it is on a Linux partition like Ext4. So the file can be managed the Linux way, with all the options about owner, group, other, read, write, execute.

Comment: It sounds like the OP might be doing this through nautilus, do you think that you could provide more detailed instructions on how to do this?

Comment: @maggotbrain - So here is the detailed description of my problem

"I am able to edit folder permissions when the folder is in an ext formatted partition no problems there , But i've several NTFS formatted partitions & i'm unable to edit folder permissions for any folder present in the NTFS formatted drive"

whenever i try to change the folder permission it reverts back to the "create & delete" option .. Is it possible to change folder permissions in an NTFS file system ??

Kindly help me sir :)

Comment: Raja, I edited your question to add the NTFS, and improved my answer. Is it ok for you?