# My question is about read,write and execute permissions of a file in Linux:

Tags: permissions

1. I've created a text file and I've assigned read only permission to that file .
2. Now when I copy that file to NTFS partition then its read only permission is vanished and I'am able to modify that file .
3. So,what happens to the permissions of file that I changed in Ext4 partition of Linux? It is not secure at all.

Comment: Sorry you are asking about permissions on NTFS = WINDOWS not linux. Please read this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/268063/how-can-i-change-the-permissions-of-a-folder-from-create-or-delete-to-list-files?rq=1 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as intended. Ext4 and NTFS use completely different permission model - POSIX-style permissions are not supported there.

When you copy the file between different types of filesystems which don't comply with the same standards, the metadata that's not supported by the target FS is lost.

That would work the same way if you set NTFS permissions for a file and then copied it to, say ext4 partition.